# How to chmod files within a python setup.py?

Tags: python, linux, security, chmod, setup.py

I created a python package installation with a setup.py, and i want it to copy a data file in the folder (created for the occasion) ~/.did. The problem is that i have to call setup.py with sudo rights, as it writes in /usr/local/... So when my data file is copied in ~/.did, only the root user has write access to the file.

I decided then to add a call to os.chmod() after the setup() function, but i'd like to know if anyone had a more clean way to do so.

Here is my setup.py file :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
import os

home=os.path.expanduser('~')

setup(name='did',
      version='1.0',
      description='Daily Image Downloader',
      author='Luc Mazon',
      author_email='my@mail.com',
      url='',
      license='GNU GPL v3',
      scripts=['did'],
      packages=['didlib'],
      data_files=[
                  ('/usr/share/man/man1', ['doc/did.1.gz']),
                  (home+'/.did', ['did.xml'])
                 ]
     )

os.chmod(home+'/.did/did.xml', 0666)
```

As did.xml is not a python file, i also created a MANIFEST.in file with the following line in it :

```
include did.xml
```

The global structure of my package is the following :

```
did-1.0
 | didlib
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | variouspyfiles.py
 | doc
 |  |-did.1.gz
 | MANIFEST.in
 | did.xml
 | did
 | setup.py
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea, since it will only be available for a single user. System-wide data should go under `/usr/share` or the like.

Comment: the file did.xml is completely user-dependent (actually, it's the configuration file for this specific-user), so i think placing it in ~/.did is good enough

Comment: Then your program should create it on first run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it would be better, and more customary, to *not* write to the installer's home directory any config files at all. What about other users?  Better would be to have your code check, on initialization, if that file exists for the user running it and only add a new one if it does not.

Comment: I should try then to install the "did.xml" file for instance in "/usr/share" during the installation, and then during the script's execution copy that file at initialization (for further custom edits)? Which place would be the best to install the file then?

Comment: @kluck That depends on how big it is. If it's small you might try just embedding the template as a triple-quoted string right inside your source code. Then write that string to the users new config file. It will automatically have the right permissions, also.

Comment: Yes, the file has about 40 lines, i could easily keep it inside my code. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

For me, you're looking either for chown (changing owner) or chgrp (changing group).

Moreover i don't see why you're making sudo, you only need right access to those files.
So just add `chmod -R gou+rx setup_dir` in order to be able to browse the installs.

Comment: The reason why i'm making sudo is because the setup.py runs the following command :

    "creating /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/didlib", and cannot do so without root access.

I'm not that good with chmod/chown/chgrp, but if i keep using sudo (as i do not see any other way for now), i guess the command    "os.chown('~/.did/did.xml', os.geteuid())"    wouldn't work because os.geteuid() should give me the root id? What should i type then?

Comment: i think, i'll execute the script using the current user, and just call the sudo when i need. By doing this I know the current user, and I have the good rights. I'm avoiding using the sudo rights.