# python - setup.py copy file to certain location

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py

As part of the installation process I would like to copy a config file to user's home directory, i.e. ~/.foo.conf

What is the usual approach to do this with `setup.py`? Should I write code in `setup.py` to copy the file after the `setup()`, or is there some built-in mechanism in place for this kind of task?

**Update**

I ended up modifying the script to check if `~/.foo.conf` exists on start up.
If not, create a default conf. I also found this [post which was useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552689).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this might be a misuse of setuptools.  If you want to stick to a setuptools install, you should probably *look* for a config file there, and advertise it loudly to your users, but if defaults are needed, they should be read from inside the package itself, using something like [`resource_stream`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#basic-resource-access) so that you can be sure you will find it no matter wether setup was run from system installed easy_install, into a virtualenv, or by a packaging system like rpm.

in the latter case, actually placing such a config file would be impractical, since the system users don't exist at the time the rpm is built.

Comment: The `resource_stream` link is now dead